# How do I connect Chart.GS to my HTML file on Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script, I am wondering how do I connect the document/chart.gs onto the html? Since the place I wanted to connect, is on here to boot:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div class="chart" style="height:184px">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
<script>
// setup 
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  
const labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
// create random Data
const helpData1 = labels.map( _ => Math.random() * 5000);
const helpData2 = labels.map( _ => Math.random() * 1000);
const helpData3 = labels.map( _ => Math.random() * 1000);
const helpData4 = labels.map( _ => Math.random() * 1000);
```

I've read the tutorial on this, however it never said anything on having the Code.Gs connect it to a setup like this.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `Using Google Apps Script, I am wondering how do I connect the document/chart.gs onto the html?`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Oh, I'm following a tutorial from here: https://netlabe.com/how-to-create-dashboard-for-free-with-google-sheets-and-chart-js-8c319ab8809b (Mostly to set up a dashboard through google sheets and Chart.JS.) Though instead of what they're using, I'm using my own Chart.JS html as to see if I can work other charts on the tutorial. However, the Chart.JS format it was in read differently(as shown above) from what the tutorial showed to be(which is this) - Cont -

Comment: Cont - 

//     Add this at the end fo <script> tag
    var ctx = document.getElementById('histogram');
    // // If you want test this locally, you should replace above line with something like this:
    // var HISTOGRAM = [{"x":"Clear", "y":501.0}, {"y":193.0, "x":"Clouds"}, {"y":2.0, "x":"Drizzle"}, {"x":"Fog", "y":3.0}, {"x":"Mist", "y":17.0}, {"y":4.0, "x":"Rain"}, {"y":2.0, "x":"Snow"}];
    var HISTOGRAM = JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(getHistogramData()); ?>);

I am not sure how do I incorporate something like this into the above.

Comment: My bad, Its my first time doing this so I'm kinda going in circles on it...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.